# Constructing variable with template in XSLT and then applying xpath

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I am using following xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:variable name="mytree">
                <xsl:call-template name="myvariable">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="count($mytree/foos/foo) &gt; 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$mytree"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <error>test</error>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="myvariable">
        <foos>
            <foo>bar1</foo>
            <foo>bar2</foo>
            <foo>bar3</foo>
            <foo>bar4</foo>
        </foos>
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i use above xslt it should be following output

```
<foos xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1">
    <foo>bar1</foo>
    <foo>bar2</foo>
    <foo>bar3</foo>
    <foo>bar4</foo>
</foos>
```

but it is

```
<error xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1">test</error>
```

when i remove the `xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"` output is proper. Not sure what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with any XML, whether constructed inside of your XSLT or read from a source, if you have elements in a certain namespace, then, to select them with XPath in XSLT, in XSLT 2 you have two options, either use `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"` (e.g. `<xsl:when test="count($mytree/foos/foo) &gt; 1" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1">`) or bind the namespace to a prefix (e.g. `<xsl:when xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1" test="count($mytree/v1:foos/v1:foo) &gt; 1">`).

You can use these approaches on an ancestor element, for instance the root element of the stylesheet, if it does not interfere with other selections you want to make.

Comment: thanks, finally i tried with  <xsl:when test="count($mytree/*:foos/*:foo) &gt; 1">

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify qualified element names in your XPath expression to address the `foos` and `foo` elements in your default namespace `http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1`:

- Register the default namespace once more with a namespace prefix (e.g. `myns`): `xmlns:myns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"`
- Use that namepace prefix in your XPath expressions to address nodes in that namespace (e.g. `myns:foos/myns:foo`).
- Add `exclude-result-prefixes="myns"` to suppress the `myns` prefix in your result document.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"

    xmlns:myns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="myns">
    …

    <xsl:template match="/">
       …
       <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count($mytree/myns:foos/myns:foo) &gt; 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$mytree"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <error>test</error>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    …
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see [XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38YY)

---

If you only had an XSLT 1.0 processor at hand, you would need the [EXSLT `node-set` function](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) to access the `$mytree` variables from the result tree:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"

    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    xmlns:myns="http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="myns">
    …

    <xsl:template match="/">
       …
       <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(exsl:node-set($mytree)/myns:foos/myns:foo) &gt; 1">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$mytree"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <error>test</error>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    …
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code for remove namespace

```
<xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.test.com/services/test/test/v1']"/>
```